# How to make a Qt widget change its size?

Tags: qt, layout, widget

My problem probably is very simple, but I have no idea how to solve it.

So, I have several widgets in vertical layout. Some of them in some moment should be invisible. I suppose this moment the control that has expanding vertical policy should increase its height but it never happens. Why? How to force it to change the size? So far there is only one way to do that - to change the size of window manually a little bit and only after it the widget changes its height.

Answer (score 3):

When you make a widget invisible (i.e. call [hide](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#hide)), also remove it from the layout (see [removeWidget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qlayout.html#removeWidget)). That way all of the other widgets will automatically resize to make use of the extra space. Since you are only hiding the widget, its space is still reserved in the vertical layout.

Make use of [insertWidget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qboxlayout.html#insertWidget) to maintain the layout ordering when transitioning a hidden widget back into view. Otherwise, [addWidget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qboxlayout.html#addWidget) would always place it at the bottom. This approach should be less complex than managing the sizes manually.

Comment: I tried this way, but it still doesn't work. The widget disappears but another widget doesn't stretches. :( Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `adjustSize()` on the parent of the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the stretch on 1 for the widget you want to be expanded when others are hidden?

```
QBoxLayout::addWidget( my_widget, 1 );
```

When this widget is added with a stretch of 1 and the other widgets without stretch, this widget will expand to the available space. Maybe that will do the trick.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't add such widget. The widget that is in layout always has expanding policy but it doesn't expand when I remove another one (with preferred policy). Thanks anyway